# Unable to access ansible dictionary item in jinja template

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I'm new to ansible/Jinja templates and trying to use a registered variable in a Jinja template, but I'm getting: **"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: list object has no element"**

Here's the ansible task registering the variable:

```
- name: get list of system users
  find:
    paths: /home
    recurse: no
    file_type: directory
  register: user_list
```

Then in the jinja template I'm trying to do the following to access that variable:

```
#Realtime scanning of downloads folder
{% for user in user_list.files %}
OnAccessIncludePath /home/{{ user_list.files[user]['gr_name'] }}/Downloads
{% endfor %}
OnAccessIncludePath /media
```

When running ansible manually, it appears the variable it registers is a list of dictionaries for each directory listing:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "examined": 2,
    "files": [
        {
            "atime": 1619032541.630475,
            "ctime": 1619032541.630475,
            "dev": 66309,
            "gid": 1000,
            "gr_name": "username1",
            "inode": 10094125,
            "isblk": false,
            "ischr": false,
            "isdir": true,
            "isfifo": false,
            "isgid": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreg": false,
            "issock": false,
            "isuid": false,
            "mode": "0775",
            "mtime": 1619032541.630475,
            "nlink": 2,
            "path": "/home/username1",
            "pw_name": "username1",
            "rgrp": true,
            "roth": true,
            "rusr": true,
            "size": 4096,
            "uid": 1000,
            "wgrp": true,
            "woth": false,
            "wusr": true,
            "xgrp": true,
            "xoth": true,
            "xusr": true
        },
        {
            "atime": 1619032541.630475,
            "ctime": 1619032541.630475,
            "dev": 66309,
            "gid": 1000,
            "gr_name": "username2",
            "inode": 10094131,
            "isblk": false,
            "ischr": false,
            "isdir": true,
            "isfifo": false,
            "isgid": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreg": false,
            "issock": false,
            "isuid": false,
            "mode": "0775",
            "mtime": 1619032541.630475,
            "nlink": 2,
            "path": "/home/username2",
            "pw_name": "username2",
            "rgrp": true,
            "roth": true,
            "rusr": true,
            "size": 4096,
            "uid": 1000,
            "wgrp": true,
            "woth": false,
            "wusr": true,
            "xgrp": true,
            "xoth": true,
            "xusr": true
        }
    ],
    "matched": 2,
    "msg": ""
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get gr_name into the config file?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this `{{ user_list.files[user]['gr_name'] }}` be `{{ user.gr_name }}`?

Comment: I get the same error with that.

Comment: ``{{ user.gr_name }}`` is the correct answer.

Comment: Oops {{ user.gr_name }} does work. I was trying {{ user_list.files.user.gr_name }}. I thought I would need the first part.

Answer (score 0):

As elyas and Vladmir Botka stated, {{ user.gr_name }} is the correct answer.